# Take a break every hour for a python script

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, multiprocessing

I have got a script which needs to run for 10 hours. For every one hour, I would like take a break for 30 sec and continue the process till test time completed.

```
def worker_1(ip, ask_time):

    time_out = time.time() + ask_time*60*60
    photo_directory = os.listdir(photo_path)

    while time.time() < time_out: 
        take_break = time.time() + 60*60

        while time.time() <= take_break:
            #Send command to device

            if time.time() == take_break:

                action = 'DoAction'
                arg_list = []
                arg_list.append(upnp_path)
                arg_list.append(' --action=')
                arg_list.append(action)
                arg_list.append(' --ip=')
                arg_list.append('34.35.35.02')

                x = subprocess.Popen(arg_list, shell=True)
                subprocess.call(["python" , arg_list])

                break 
                print "Sleep time 30 secs ..."

            else:
                for photo in photo_directory:

                    choice_photos_list = list()    
                    image_name = ["john", "Sue", "lee"]    
                    random_choice = random.choice(image_name)

                    if photo.lower().startswith(random_choice):

                        choice_photos_list.append(photo)

                        for choice_photo in choice_photos_list:
                            action = 'CancelAction'
                            arg_list = []
                            arg_list.append(upnp_path)
                            arg_list.append(' --action=')
                            arg_list.append(action)
                            arg_list.append(' --ip=')
                            arg_list.append('34.35.35.02')
                            arg_list.append(' --img=')
                            arg_list.append(choice_photo)

                            x = subprocess.Popen(arg_list, shell=True)

                            subprocess.call(["python" , arg_list])

                            time.sleep(30)
```

subprocess ends when total time is completed. But it does take break every one hour. Any ideas would be really appreciated.

Comment: You are likely to not get a time event exactly at your break time. Change the condition `if time.time() == take_break:` to `if time.time() >= take_break:` and the program might do what you want.

Comment: @JohanL I think that should be an answer

Comment: @e4c5 Maybe, but there are some more oddities with the original code, which I do not want to examine further, so further modifications might be needed.

Comment: Thanks @JohanL for your help. I've tried your answer, but it did not stop the process.

Comment: Well, you probably need to put in a `time.sleep(30)` somewhere as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def worker_1():
    import time
    Minute, Hourcount, Match = int(time.strftime("%M")), 0, time.strftime("%S")
    while Hourcount < 10:
        #Do Something
        if int(time.strftime("%M")) == Minute:
            if Match == time.strftime("%S"):
                time.sleep(30)
                Hourcount += 1
                Match = time.strftime("%S")
```

I copied and addapted some code I once wrote. Use this as your foundation, and build it up according to your specific needs.